# Chrome incognito mode : config url

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to configure my Chrome so that when i open a new tab in incognito mode (ctrl shift N) it open a new tab and automatically go to an URL, instead of the empty tab.
Is there a way or an add-on to do that?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to automatically change to incognito if you try and access certain URLs, which you could then bookmark so when you click them it opens incognite? You can use Ghost incognito for this, just make sure you enable the app for use in incognito mode. You then go to the url and press the ghost icon.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghost-incognito/gedeaafllmnkkgbinfnleblcglamgebg

Comment: Actually for the moment i just Ctrl Shift N and clic on a bookmark, but i do that like 100 times per day, just want to save some time by just having to "Ctrl Shift N"

Comment: If you use Ghost incognito, then you don't need to use Ctrl Shift N, you just press the Bookmark in normal mode, and it will switch specific URLs to incognito automatically. Link added to Answer above.